# Drush make and multisite

Tags: drush, multi-sites

I am building a multisite and each sub-site may have its own contrib modules.

For example:
sites/all/modules/contrib/entity
sites/site1/modules/contrib/views
sites/site2/modules/contrib/services

I build a makefile for the shared modules:

```
api = 2
core = 7.x
projects[entity][] = ""
```

And one makefile per subsite which includes the global makefile:

```
includes[] = "make.yml"
projects[views][] = ""
```

The inclusion works properly but I can't get the modules being downloaded in different directories.

I try to run the drush make command with *--contrib-destination=sites* option, add *defaults[projects][subdir] = all/modules/contrib* in the global makefile and to specify a subdir for each sub-sites's specific module *projects[views][subdir] = "sites1/modules/contrib"*. No luck, the modules are downloaded in *sites/modules/all/modules/contrib* and *sites/modules/site1/modules/contrib* instead.

Is there any way to get it working? I now think to add some custom code to a script to run after the drush make command to move specific modules to proper directory.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

By checking the drush code itself, we discovered the possibility to add contrib_destination on specific project level.

```
projects[views][] = ""
projects[views][contrib_destination] = "sites/site1"
```

However, as it would had quite a lot of lines to the makefile (we must add the contrib_destination line to all modules used by site1 only) we decided to not use the includes feature and to keep to separate makefiles.

To build our docroot, we then have one "global" makefile to prepare the sites/all modules and another ones for each subsites (sites/site1). Then we launch the drush make command for each makefile (using a shell wrapper to handle it).

This is not perfect and would probably be easier to have something build-in (I don't know what would be the best syntax for that).